# Uwp app can't connect to Wcf service using net.tcp

Tags: c#, wcf, uwp, net.tcp

I have a Wcf service that is successfully used by WinForm app and asp.net site inside intranet. Now I am rewriting WinForm app to Uwp app. I have latest Framework 4.7.2 and Net.Core 2.1 installed. How can I consume my service from Uwp? I tryed connecting to my service using:

```
        var binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport);
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;
        WcfService.WcfServiceClient wcf_client = new
                        WcfService.WcfServiceClient();
        wcf_client.Endpoint.Binding = binding;
        wcf_client.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("net.tcp://server:8089/TeamCity");
        wcf_client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "user";
        wcf_client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "password";
```

After I call my service:

```
var towers = await wcf_client.GetTowersAsync();
```

I get an error:

> at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at UwpApp.MainPage.d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.b__6_0(Object state)
>      at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeCore()

Comment: Could you please provide the exception detail message?  Not only the stack trace.  And your uwp app target version as well.

Comment: @Sunteen Wu I tryed another code. Got The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:59.7099734'.

Comment: Have you enabled the `Enterprise Authentication` and `Private Networks(Client & Server)` capabilities? And additional, please avoid to put the question as answer. Please edit it to your original thread.